# Monolog in Firebug is not working.

Tags: laravel-5, firebug, monolog

I am trying to do a simple test with Firebug in Mozilla, however it is not working, nothing appear in the firebug console. This my code:

```
public function index()
{
      $monolog = \Log::getMonolog();

      $items = ['Pack luggage', 'Go to airport', 'Arrive in San Juan'];

      $monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler());

      $monolog->addInfo('Log Message', array('items' => $items));

      return view('welcome');
}
```

Firefox version: 38.0.1, Firebug version: 2.0.9 and FirePHP 0.7.4. I read some post and I think the problem maybe is Firefox. Any suggestion please? Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable "net panels".

1. Click on the firebug icon
2. Select the arrow on the right of "Net"
3. Click on "Enable"

Answer (score 0):

Even you have installed FireBug, you additionally have to install the extension FirePHP - it is FireBug extension.
Of course the console has to be enabled too :)